# Slideshow header height does not go according to my CSS attribute

Tags: css

Why doesn't my slideshow header change according to my CSS attributes?

This is basically how my slideshow header works

```
<div id="Slideshow">
<img src="image/s1.jpg" name="slide">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var step = 1
function slideit() {
    document.images.slide.src = eval("image" + step + ".src")
    if (step < 5)
        step++
    else
        step = 1
    setTimeout("slideit()", 2500)
}
slideit()
//-->
</script>
</div>
```

As you can see i declared the CSS covering the slideshow as "Slideshow"

This is my "slideshow" CSS

```
#Slideshow
{
  position:absolute;
  top:121px;
  left:0%;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0px;
  height:150px;
}
```

Despite adding the width/height attributes, the slideshow does not change visually.

Comment: couple of things, probably a good idea to make a jsfiddle to help us help you faster, the other is that when you declare 0 its zero, you dont need to explicitly say % , em, px, etc. Also, how come your javascript has some html comment?

Answer (score 0):

I see these properties working fine. I set this up:

**[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/NKpTF/)**

So you can see it working, it's positioning 121 pixels from the top, and I made the background black so you can see it's the right height of 150px.

I also went ahead and cleaned the formatting on the CSS a bit by giving it spaces and getting rid of some leftover characters next to the Zeros'

```
#Slideshow {
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 121px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I should also mentioned that I added the `overflow: hidden;` because the image I had was too big so the `overflow: hidden;` prevents the overflow of the element (in this case an image) from it's parent container.

Let me know if this clarified your question.

Comment: I get what you mean there by overflow:hidden which cuts off the picture beyond 150px. However, is there a way i can make all picture at the height of 150px. I know resolution may come into concern but that's not my priority at the moment. Regards

Comment: Yes there is... but I need a little bit more info to put the fiddle together for you. Can you update your post with the images that you want to use? For me the only concern is that the picture will lose it's aspect ratio if it's not handled properly, so this depends on the images you will use and how much control over the crop you will need.

Comment: Here is another fiddle that has a big image that is being resized 100% width of it's parent container, therefor the height is covered completely. http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/wgrq4/

Comment: What i meant is i group my slideshow under a css called "slideshow" but putting a height attribute doesn't help to change the height of the slideshow. The jsfiddle's height you provided also doesn't change.

Comment: Do you want the height to be fixed at 150px or should 150px be the minimum height? Meaning that if the image is bigger then the height will grow too?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34119/discussion-between-sulfureous-and-teo-chuen-wei-bryan)

Comment: What i meant was adjusting the height of my slideshow header to a specific px.

Comment: Yes, right now it's set to 150px ... you can change that value to anything you want and it will stay fixed even if the elements inside it are bigger.